# Telerik Grid MVC Razor : auto select a row and fire select event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik

Using a Telerik Grid with ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor engine.

When a user selects a row, we un-hide some part of the page. This is working fine when I click on a row.

However, I need to automatically select the first row when the page is loaded

I can change the row display color so it appears selected, but I can't figure out how to have the select event called!

Here is the grid code :

```
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid<SomethingViewModel>()
            .Name("SomethingGroupGrid")
            .ClientEvents(events =>
                {
                    events.OnDataBinding("SomethingGroupGrid_onDataBinding");
                })
                    .DataBinding(dataBingding => dataBingding.Ajax().Select("SomethingGroupGrid", "Something"))
            .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden();
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Name)
                    .Title("Groups");
                })
            .Selectable()
            .Pageable(x => x.PageSize(10))
            .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowSelect("SomethingGroupGrid_RowSelect"))


         )
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a freakishly ugly solution :

I added a OnRowDataBound event on the grid. This OnRowDatabound Functions fires the OnRowSelect events.
Then I added page global javascript variable to hold a bool value that checks if the first row has been selected, so the OnRowDatabound does not call OnRowSelect for each row.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<SomethingViewModel>()
        .Name("SomethingGroupGrid")
        .ClientEvents(events =>
            {
                events.OnDataBinding("SomethingGroupGrid_onDataBinding");
            })
                .DataBinding(dataBingding => dataBingding.Ajax().Select("SomethingGroupGrid", "Something"))
        .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden();
                columns.Bound(c => c.Name)
                .Title("Groups");
            })
        .Selectable()
        .Pageable(x => x.PageSize(10))
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowSelect("SomethingGroupGrid_RowSelect"))
        .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("SomethingGroupGrid_OnRowDataBound"))


     )
<script type="text/javascript">
      var firstRowSelected = false;

      function PreviewAccountGrid_DataBound(e) {

      if (firstRowSelected == false) {
          SomethingGroupGrid_RowSelect(e);
          firstRowSelected = true;
       }
       }

</script>
```

Plese tell me that there is a better way to do that, or it will severely degrade my opinion of Telerik controls (which is already damn low).